# "undefined function sqlsrv_connect()" in PHP + SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, dll

I developed an application in CodeIgniter with SQL Server connection.
In my development environment all went well, when I move to the production environment (elsewhere), errors occurred.

**Informations:**

- PHP Version 5.6.18
- Windows Server 2008 (x64)
- Apache 2.4.18 (Win64)
- SQLServer Express Edition 10.50.1600.1

I added the following DLLs in the "ext" folder:

- php_pdo_mysql.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

And added in my php.ini the following lines:

- extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Even so, the following error occurs:

```
Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

(http://prntscr.com/a4ik36)

I tried many other similar topics here in the forum and the most was the lack of enabling the extension in php.ini, which is not my case ...

Comment: You restarted Apache after changes to ini file?

Comment: Yes, restart apache every time I change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the full deployment, downloaded again php, apache, DLLs, SQL connector, etc., and is now functioning normally. I imagine something previously was with x64 mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the case.

There are two `php.ini` files.

```
1) Under php folder. // My Path : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12

2) Under apache folder // My path : C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin
```

You need to add that extension lines in both of the file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is not my case! In my php "Loaded Configuration File" is "C:\WebServer\php\php.ini". I alter the correct file

Comment: Did you alter file under apache? If no, please try once.